# mouse pressed detection on image link

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build an image were I can press any button and get if there is a Right, Left, ou Double click.

like these:

```
    <img id="myImgId" alt="" src="image.jpeg"   onmousedown="click(event)"/>
    <p><span id="click"></span></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
function click(event)
{
    if(event.button==2) 
    {
        document.getElementById("click").innerHTML="Last Action: Right Click";
        document.getElementById("click").value="Last Action: Right Click";
    }
    else if(event.button=0)
    {
        if(event.getclickcount() = 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("click").innerHTML="Last Action: Left Click";
            document.getElementById("click").value="Last Action: Left Click";
        }
        else if(event.getclickcount() = 2)
        {
            document.getElementById("click").innerHTML="Last Action: Double Click";
            document.getElementById("click").value="Last Action: Double Click";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I was expecting that when I clicked the image, this would do something....

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: It does do nothing :<

Comment: Thanks for telling us.

Comment: This might be helpfull: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: you're triggering on mousedown. at that point, there's only been a "down" click, and no release, so there's no way you can detect a doubleclick - you have to release+reclick the button before you can get that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want you to know that Javascript **isn't** Java! *getClickCount()* is a Java method, not a Javascript one.

Then, I suggest you this reading: [Mouse Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events)

One last thing. When you use *getElementById* it returns an HTMLElement. If this element is a span, you don't need to set its **value**, because its innerHTML is enough!

If you just need to check those three events there are some builtin methods that allow you to do something similar, here is a little snippet that shows you interaction between different type of clicks and HTML:

**HTML part**

```
<img id="myImgId" alt="" src="image.jpeg" />
<p><span id="click"></span></p>
```

**Javascript code**

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myImgId'),
    clickSpan = document.getElementById('click'),
    events = {
        click: 'Left',
        contextmenu: 'Right',
        dblclick: 'Double'
    };
function changeClickSpanValue(eventType) {
    clickSpan.innerHTML = 'Last Action: ' + events[eventType] + ' Click';
}
myImg.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeClickSpanValue('click')
};
myImg.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeClickSpanValue('contextmenu');
}
myImg.ondblclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeClickSpanValue('dblclick');
}
```

See the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LbSqD/)

Comment: This is what happens when you work in too many places with too many languages without that many experience, really... thank you

Comment: I've added the document.myform.submit(); to this, how could I use a timer in the left button to prevent from blocking the double click

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want your submit form button not to be allowed to be double clicked?

Comment: Why don't you only block the dblclick with the ondblclick event? It's easy, just point to your submit button(if it has an id, use document.getElementById('buttonId').ondblclick, else you can both use document.myform.submit.ondblclick) and assign this function: function(e) {e.preventDefault();} this will prevent dblclick event for your submit button. Is this what you are looking for?